# Cambiar posicion al div cuando doy click AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angularjs

Estoy tratando de posicionar el cuadro `azul`dependiendo del cuadro al que le doy `click`, es decir que si le doy `click` al cuadro verde, el cuadro azul debe de bajar hasta donde esta el cuadro verde,no puede quedar arriba del todo, debe quedar como si le colocara la propiedad `top: 500px;` de `css` o algo así.

```html
<html>
   <head>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []); 
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

        $scope.showFuncion = function() {
          $scope.showDiv = true;
          $scope.fafa = !$scope.fafa
        }
    });
    </script>
   
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <div style="height: 150px; background-color: red;" ng-click="showFuncion()">
            ESTE ES EL LADO DERECHO DE LA PANTALLA
          </div>
          <div style="height: 150px; background-color: yellow;" ng-click="showFuncion()">
            ESTE ES EL LADO DERECHO DE LA PANTALLA
          </div>
          <div style="height: 150px; background-color: green;" ng-click="showFuncion()">
            ESTE ES EL LADO DERECHO DE LA PANTALLA
          </div>
          <div style="height: 150px; background-color: pink;" ng-click="showFuncion()">
            ESTE ES EL LADO DERECHO DE LA PANTALLA
          </div>
          <div style="height: 150px; background-color: black;" ng-click="showFuncion()">
            ESTE ES EL LADO DERECHO DE LA PANTALLA
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6" ng-cloak ng-if="showDiv && fafa">
          <div style="height: 150px; background-color: blue;">
            ESTE ES EL LADO IZQUEIRDO DE LA PANTALLA
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>


   </body>
</html>
```

Este es el error de `offsetTop` que me muestra en 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He hecho los siguientes cambios a tu código:

1. He añadido `$event` como parámetro en la funciones que se llaman desde el `ng-click`. Esto es para poder luego leer el elemento sobre el que se hizo click.
2. Al elemento que queremos posicionar, le he añadido un `ng-style` (con valor "miEstilo") y en los estilos CSS le he puesto una posición relativa (para que al cambiar el `top` se mueva.
3. En la función llamada, leo el elemento sobre el que se hizo click (con `$event.currentTarget`) y veo en qué posición desde arriba está situado (con `offsetTop`).
4. Finalmente, cambio `miEstilo` para especificar el valor de `top` a tantos píxeles como se encuentre el elemento clickeado.

El código se ve así:

```html
<html>
   <head>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []); 
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

        $scope.showFuncion = function($event) {

          $scope.miEstilo = {'top': $event.currentTarget.offsetTop + 'px'}
          $scope.showDiv = true;
          $scope.fafa = !$scope.fafa
        }
    });
    </script>
   
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <div style="height: 150px; background-color: red;" ng-click="showFuncion($event)">
            ESTE ES EL LADO DERECHO DE LA PANTALLA
          </div>
          <div style="height: 150px; background-color: yellow;" ng-click="showFuncion($event)">
            ESTE ES EL LADO DERECHO DE LA PANTALLA
          </div>
          <div style="height: 150px; background-color: green;" ng-click="showFuncion($event)">
            ESTE ES EL LADO DERECHO DE LA PANTALLA
          </div>
          <div style="height: 150px; background-color: pink;" ng-click="showFuncion($event)">
            ESTE ES EL LADO DERECHO DE LA PANTALLA
          </div>
          <div style="height: 150px; background-color: black;" ng-click="showFuncion($event)">
            ESTE ES EL LADO DERECHO DE LA PANTALLA
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6" ng-cloak ng-if="showDiv && fafa">
          <div ng-style="miEstilo" style="height: 150px; background-color: blue; position: relative;">
            ESTE ES EL LADO IZQUEIRDO DE LA PANTALLA
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>


   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias justamente lo que necesitaba.

Comment: estoy aplicando tu respuesta pero me dice que no tiene offsetTop puedes mirar la pregunta editada para que veas la imagen...

Comment: @Pablo ¿cómo están posicionados los elementos? ¿qué valor tiene en `top`?

Comment: pues no tienen nada en top, es '0'

Comment: estoy usando una librería con bower_components, se llama angular-material-expasion-panel

Comment: @Pablo la idea es la misma, solo tienes que encontrar un valor que te valga (si recuerdo bien, ya hay alguna pregunta en el sitio sobre cómo calcular la posición vertical de un elemento dado). Entonces cuando lo encuentres, usa ese en lugar del offsetTop

Comment: @AlvaroMontana acabo de notar algo y es que los elementos que uso tienen una position: static, creo que al cambiarla relative estos me dan una opción por la cual elegir, ya resolví mis duda, gracias gracias.

Comment: @Pablo genial! Siento que mis comentarios no hayan sido muy de ayuda, pero estoy en el móvil y no tengo mucha capacidad de mirar código aquí.

Comment: muy buena pregunta...

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ahora mismo tengo un problema en posicionar un div cunado le doy click a otro.